# "Awkward surprise" exclamation

Tags: word-usage, expressions

Here in my country some uses the word "misericórdia", that in english means "mercy", as an exclamation after a fright or to express some disgust over something. Would using the word "mercy" in these situations sound odd?

Comment: Actually "Mercy!" is also an exclamation of shock or surprise in English ... however it's use is *regional* and possibly *age-* and even *gender*-related.  So it could sound odd if you don't fit the profile of the kind of person who would use it, in a region where it is common.

Comment: Oh, mercy me...

Answer (score 2):

The use of

> **mercy**

as an exclamation can be used in situation of shock or surprise and is a shortened form of

> **Lord have mercy**, or
>   **Mercy me**

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Andrew's comment:

> Actually "Mercy!" is also an exclamation of shock or surprise in English ... however, its use is regional and possibly age- and even gender-related. So it could sound odd if you don't fit the profile of the kind of person who would use it, in a region where it is common.

Here's a good list of alternatives that range from the polite to the downright crude:

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Thesaurus:wow#English

Here are some very mild ones that I think are similar to "Mercy!":

> Oh my!
>
> Oh my gosh!
>
> Oh my goodness!

Other expressions that don't sound as *modest* as those in the previous list but aren't swear words either:

> Wow!
>
> Jeez!
>
> Whoa!
>
> What the...!

More offensive (especially to religious audiences):

> Jesus Christ!
>
> Oh my God!
>
> Damn!

Most crude:

> Oh shit!
>
> Holy shit!

etc.

Comment: You could pick some of the more common expressions from that very long list to include here. The list doesn't indicate which are general purpose and which are regional.  Most people won't be saying "Begorra!" or "Gadzooks" to express surprise.